# how can I edit my code while debugging or attaching to another process?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an application I want to debug for a long time, days or more. Meanwhile I want to edit it's code without affecting the run that's in progress.

I have 2 problems here:

1. If I change the source code I can't enter break mode anymore, seens the source is different than it was on compilation.
   In order to fix it I made a copy of my solution, ran it and attached to the process.
2. When I enter debug mode (throught attaching to a process) any source code on my solution becomes "readonly" so I can't work on it.

How can I edit a project while debugging or attaching?
And than is there a better way to change my code without affecting the debugging process than making a copy?

Comment: Can't you run the long time project using `exe` file in debug folder and use open and run other projects in VS ?

Comment: I can, but I need to debug that long time project, not just run it